# ARP Spoofing from Ubuntu

Tags: networking, kernel, security, ethernet, arp

I receive ARP Spoofing alerts in my network coming from an Ubuntu
server that I have just installed.

the server have two network cards that are connected to the same network with
different IPs.

```
$ lsb_release -a

  No LSB modules are available.
  Distributor ID: Ubuntu
  Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS
  Release:        22.04
  Codename:       jammy
```

.

```
$ cat /etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml

  network:
    ethernets:
      eno1:
        optional: true
        match:
          driver: e1000e
          macaddress: 80:ee:73:f5:b4:dc
        addresses: [192.168.200.101/24]
        routes:
          - to: 192.168.200.0
            via: 192.168.200.101
            on-link: True
          - to: default
            via: 192.168.200.250
        nameservers:
          addresses: [192.168.230.231, 8.8.8.8]
      enp1s0:
        optional: true
        match:
          driver: igb
          macaddress: 80:ee:73:f5:b4:db
        addresses: [192.168.200.102/24]
        routes:
          - to: 192.168.200.0
            via: 192.168.200.102
            on-link: true
    version: 2
```

.

```
$ ip a

  1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
      link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
      inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  2: enp1s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 80:ee:73:f5:b4:db brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      inet 192.168.200.102/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global enp1s0
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
  3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
      link/ether 80:ee:73:f5:b4:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
      altname enp0s31f6
      inet 192.168.200.101/24 brd 192.168.200.255 scope global eno1
         valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

.

```
$ ip r

  default via 192.168.200.250 dev eno1 proto static
  192.168.200.0/24 dev eno1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.200.101
  192.168.200.0/24 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.200.102
```

.

```
$ route

  Kernel IP routing table
  Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
  default         18b169909b80    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eno1
  192.168.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eno1
  192.168.200.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 enp1s0
```

messages on Eset Nod32

```
Date and time;Event;Action;Source;Target;Protocol;Rule/worm name;Application path;Application;Hash;User;Signer;Package name;Service
08/11/2023 11:36:00;ARP cache poisoning attack;Blocked;192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4:db];192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4 :dc];ARP;;;;;;;;
08/11/2023 11:36:01;ARP cache poisoning attack;Blocked;192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4:db];192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4 :dc];ARP;;;;;;;;
08/11/2023 11:36:02;ARP cache poisoning attack;Blocked;192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4:db];192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4 :dc];ARP;;;;;;;;
08/11/2023 11:36:03;ARP cache poisoning attack;Blocked;192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4:db];192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4 :dc];ARP;;;;;;;;
08/11/2023 11:36:04;ARP cache poisoning attack;Blocked;192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4:db];192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4 :dc];ARP;;;;;;;;
08/11/2023 11:36:05;ARP cache poisoning attack;Blocked;192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4:db];192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4 :dc];ARP;;;;;;;;
08/11/2023 11:36:06;ARP cache poisoning attack;Blocked;192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4:db];192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4 :dc];ARP;;;;;;;;
08/11/2023 11:36:07;ARP cache poisoning attack;Blocked;192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4:db];192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4 :dc];ARP;;;;;;;;
08/11/2023 11:36:08;ARP cache poisoning attack;Blocked;192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4:db];192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4 :dc];ARP;;;;;;;;
08/11/2023 11:36:09;ARP cache poisoning attack;Blocked;192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4:db];192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4 :dc];ARP;;;;;;;;
08/11/2023 11:36:10;ARP cache poisoning attack;Blocked;192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4:db];192.168.200.101 [80:ee:73:f5:b4 :dc];ARP;;;;;;;;
```

Comment: I would never put two NICs on the same sub-net. But I do not know for certain if that is your issue or not.